# How to split a string into sentences cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, string, nsstring

I have an `NSString` with a number of sentences, and I'd like to split it into an `NSArray` of sentences. Has anybody solved this problem before? I found `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` which is able to do it, but it looks like it isn't available on the iPhone (Snow Leopard only). I thought about splitting the string based on periods, but that doesn't seem very robust.

So far my best option seems to be to use RegexKitLite to regex it into an array of sentences. Solutions?

Comment: Define "sentence". Once you can do that, a solution is straightforward.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone else had come up with a reasonably robust definition of a sentence already. I wish to stand on the shoulders of giants!

Comment: If you look at TeX, it guesses that periods mark the end of sentences except where they come immediately after a capital letter - if that's not right, you have to manually specify whether it's a fullstop or simply an abbreviation mark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate Full Sentences in a block of NSString text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402492/separate-full-sentences-in-a-block-of-nsstring-text)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [CFStringTokenizer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringTokenizerRef/). You'll want to create the tokenizer with the `kCFStringTokenizerUnitSentence` option.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a scanner for it,

```
NSScanner *sherLock = [NSCanner scannerWithString:yourString]; // autoreleased
NSMutableArray *theArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // autoreleased
while( ![sherLock isAtEnd] ){
   NSString *sentence = @"";
   // . + a space, your sentences probably will have that, and you
   // could try scanning for a newline \n but iam not sure your sentences
   // are seperated by it
   [sherLock scanUpToString:@". " inToString:&sentence];
   [theArray addObject:sentence];
}
```

This should do it, there could be some little mistakes in it but this is how I would do it.
You should lookup NSScanner in the docs though.. you might come across a method that is
better for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used them for a while but I think you can do this with NSString, NSCharacterSet and NSScanner. You create a character set that holds end sentence punctuation and then call `-[NSScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:]`. Each Scan will suck out a sentence into a string and you keep calling the method until the scanner runs out of string.

Of course, the text has to be well punctuated.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
NSArray *sentences = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@". "];
```

This will return an array("One","Two","Three") from a string "One. Two. Three."

Comment: How about "My friend Dr. Mark received a Ph.D. from St. Jude's."

Comment: Yeah, I tried that method after I posted the question. It worked better than just scanning for "." but not much.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *sentences = [astring componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet  punctuationCharacterSet] ];