# Separate Full Sentences in a block of NSString text

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have been trying to use Regular Expression to separate full sentences in a big block of text. I can't use the componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet because it will obviously fail with sentences ending in ?!, !!, ... I have seen some external classes to do componentSeparateByRegEx but I prefer doing it without adding an external library.

Here is a sample input 
**Hi, I am testing. How are you? Wow!! this is the best, and I am happy.**

The output should be an array

first element: **Hi, I am testing.**

second element:  **How are you?**

third element: **wow!!**

forth element: **this is the best, and I am happy.**

This is what I have but as I mentioned it shouldn't do what I intend. Probably a regular expression will do a much better job here.

```
-(NSArray *)getArrayOfFullSentencesFromBlockOfText:(NSString *)textBlock{
    NSMutableCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc] init];
    [characterSet addCharactersInString:@".?!"];  
    NSArray * sentenceArray = [textBlock componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet];                                   
    return sentenceArray;  
}
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use `-[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:]` with the `NSStringEnumerationBySentences` option. This will give you every sentence, and it does so in a language-aware manner.

```
NSArray *fullSentencesFromText(NSString *text) {
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    [text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [text length]) options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [results addObject:substring];
    }];
    return results;
}
```

Note, in testing, each substring appears to contain the trailing spaces after the punctuation. You may want to strip those out.

Comment: @FazYa: "Hi" with no punctuation is still a sentence. If you really want to filter that out you could check if the very last result has any punctuation at the end and throw it out if not. As for localized, use that if the text is expected to belong to the user's default locale (e.g. if it's user-entered text it probably will), but don't use it if you expect the text to be agnostic of the user's default locale.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could do the job:

```
NSString *msg = @"Hi, I am testing. How are you? Wow!! this is the best, and I am happy.";
[msg enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [msg length])
                        options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences | NSStringEnumerationLocalized
                     usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSLog(@"Sentence:%@", substring);       
    // Add each sentence into an array                                                                 
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have 2 concerns about using the internal NSStringEnumerationBySentences. First, it still returns a full sentence when I dont have a sentence at all. Example: Hi, returns one sentence. This could be more of a behavior thing but can I make it not add any element if there is no full sentence? 2- Do I need to add in the NSStringEnumerationLocalized?

Comment: @FazYa I think Kevin answered to both of your concerns. Now... 'Hi' is not a sentence with the strict [linguistic definition of 'sentence'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics)) but if you're willing to dive deeper into this you could consider using a [CFStringTokenizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringTokenizerRef/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
    [mutstri enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [mutstri length])
                                options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences
                             usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){

                                 NSLog(@"%@", substring);

                             }];
```